# How to convert string to wchar_t when string is stored in a variable?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

To convert a string literal to `wchar_t` we can use `L` like:

`wchar_t variable[10] = L"some text"`;`

But if the string is stored inside a variable then how do I convert it to `wchar_t`?

Suppose the string is in a variable

`string varString="someText";`

I want to store it in a variable of type `wchar_t`, for example `wchar_t var;`

How do I type cast and store it?

I want to place the variables inside a loop where their values will change with each cycle:

```
for(i=0;i<10;i++)
{  
   var=(*some kind of casting*)varString;
}
```

Comment: No.. I have edited to include some more details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two different ways...depending on simplicity... This is in Visual C++ group...

So first I would try using CStringW.  Depending on #defines your regular CString might be a CStringA or CStringW. But, you can say CStringW.

```
CStringW sWide = "abcdef"; // uses current thread code page
const wchar_t* pWide = sWide.GetString(); // pointer only valid for scope of sWide
```

Or you can use MultiByteToWideChar() API.

```
wchar_t wszBuf[512];
MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, 0, "abcdef", 6, wszBuf, _countof(wszBuf)); // substitute "abcdef" and the 6 (length) for your usage...
```